Which of these implementations is canonical: storing the head and size variables, or storing the head, tail, and size?
For a singly linked list, should I store the head and size variables, or the head, tail, and size?

Those are two different questions: what is canonical is not always the same as what you need. And what you need depends on your use case which you haven't provided.

Only the head field is a canonical. You can trivially implement getSize() and getTailNode() methods with only the head node available.
Storing size and tail as fields is optional, they are not a fundamental part of the "linked list" concept. Having them does benefit the complexity of certain operations though, at the cost of having to store and correctly update them.

In a singly linked list, you can store just the head and size variables, but including the tail as well can offer several benefits depending on your use case.
